# Select people from database based on their age

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm working on an SQLite database. I need to obtain a list of people who have between a minimum age and a maximum age.

In my table `person`, I have a column *login* and a column *birth*.

I have already tried this method (only for minimum age), with no result:

```
SELECT login FROM person WHERE ((JulianDay('now')) - (JulianDay(birth))/365) > 5
```

Do you have an idea why that doesn't work?

Comment: Provide sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you do `n - m / 365` and division is done before subtraction. :-)

```
(JulianDay('now') - JulianDay(birth)) / 365
```

Comment: Thank you :) Too much time passed on an easy subject

Answer (score 1):

You have misplaced your brackets. You have to use below query for correct result.

```
SELECT  login FROM person WHERE ((JulianDay('now') - JulianDay(birth))/365) > 5
```